# How can I get Sqlalchemy to preserve column order in the sql it generates?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Sqlalchemy doesn't seem to preserve the column order when it generates sql for a table. How can I get sqlalchemy to use the same order that columns are defined?

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, BigInteger, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey, Date, DateTime

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Base = declarative_base()


class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    col1 = Column(String(20), name="col1")
    col2 = Column(Integer)
    col3 = Column(BigInteger, name="col_3")

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
db = Session()

print(db.query(MyTable).statement.compile(engine))
```

Output is:

```
SELECT my_table.col_3, my_table.id, my_table.col1, my_table.col2
FROM my_table
```

instead of

```
SELECT my_table.id, my_table.col1, my_table.col2, my_table.col_3
FROM my_table
```

Sqlalchemy does seem to preserve the column order in the table definition because when it generates the CREATE TABLE command, the column order matches the order columns are defined.

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
print(CreateTable(MyTable.__table__).compile(engine))
```

Answer (score 4):

The columns are stored differently in the mapper than in the table.  When you do `CreateTable(MyTable.__table__)` it [looks through `columns` on the table](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/3e3f9e8488253e5ccf4e37a46d234f7724974f4a/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py?at=rel_0_9#cl-478).  When you do `session.query(MyTable)` it [looks through `_props` on the current mapper](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/3e3f9e8488253e5ccf4e37a46d234f7724974f4a/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py?at=rel_0_9#cl-3237).  `_props` is not populated in the same way as `columns`, and due to some decisions in SQLAlchemy internals this can result in a different order.

The answer is ultimately no, you cannot guarantee the order of queried columns because there are other forces at work behind the scenes.  If order really matters to you, it should probably be [brought up as an issue](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues) against SQLAlchemy.

In this case, assigning a column name that does not match the attribute name changes the order that the column is stored internally.  Removing `name='col_3'` from that column will "fix" this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit funny, but if you change col_3 to col3 it emits the columns as declared.

Why is that ?

When the mapper configuration is executed there is this comment

```
        # look through columns in the current mapper that
        # are keyed to a propname different than the colname
        # (if names were the same, we'd have popped it out above,
        # in which case the mapper makes this combination).
        # See if the superclass has a similar column property.
        # If so, join them together.
```

your col_3 is going to the properties argument of the mapper class which will be used as the first arguments of the selectable.

Comment: Can you clarify what file you are looking at, and how can I modify it to get the columns in the declared order?

Comment: declarative/base.py and orm/mapper.py. Change the name of the column (Column(name=...)) to match the property name.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem using raw sql, like

```
result = session.execute(f"select * from <table_name> where <table_name>.<column_name> = required parameter")
result.all()
```

this way you get your column order according to table column order